# SQL Compact: Select From DatabaseOne.SomeTable, Join DatabaseTWO.SomeOtherTable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce

I'm working on SQL Compact 3.5 (Microsoft). Is something like this possible? ::- ).

```
Select From DatabaseOne.SomeTable, Join DatabaseTWO.SomeOtherTable
```

I need to join data from 2 different databases which I have loaded in SQL Server Management Studio (from 2 different files). So I'm connected to both of them and I can switch between using one or another via the `USE` keyword, but I don't know how to use both databases in the same time in a `JOIN`.

Comment: Can you create database link in SQL Serverer CE? This is the way we achieve this in Oracle.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "database link". Yes, I see both servers in the Database Explorer. I got no option for a "link" or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, you must move all data to a single SQL Compact file.